# Displaying a 2d array JAVAFX

Tags: java, arrays, loops, javafx

I'm trying to add all the values from different arrays to one 2d array and display it as a table in JavaFX.

Here's my try in doing it.

```
private StackPane table(Stage stage) {

    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    String[][] staffArray = new String[365][365];

    staffArray[0][0] = "No. ";
    staffArray[0][1] = "Check in";
    staffArray[0][2] = "Check out";
    staffArray[0][3] = "Name";
    staffArray[0][4] = "Surname";

    System.out.println(String.valueOf(arrRoom1[0][0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < arrRoom1.length; i++) {

        for (int y = 1; y < arrRoom1.length; y++) {
            if (arrRoom1[i] == null) {
                break;
            }

            staffArray[y][0] = String.valueOf(y);
            staffArray[y][1] = String.valueOf(arrRoom1[i][0]);
            staffArray[y][2] = String.valueOf(arrRoom1[i][1]);
            staffArray[y][3] = String.valueOf(names1[i]);
            staffArray[y][4] = String.valueOf(surnames1[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(staffArray[1][1]);

    ObservableList<String[]> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    data.addAll(Arrays.asList(staffArray));
    data.remove(0);//remove titles from data
    TableView<String[]> table = new TableView<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < staffArray.length; i++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            if ( staffArray[i][y] == null) {
                break;
            }
            TableColumn tc = new TableColumn(staffArray[i][y]);

        final int colNo = i;
        tc.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String[], String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String[], String> p) {
                return new SimpleStringProperty((p.getValue()[colNo]));
            }
        });
        tc.setPrefWidth(90);
        table.getColumns().add(tc);
    }
}
    table.setItems(data);
    root.getChildren().add(table);
    return root;
}
```

However, every time I get null values in staffArray after the loop. Where might the mistake be in the nested loop?